# Replace onKeyUp with onBlur jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input class="text  empty" type="text" size="20" name="Email" id="Email" value="" onkeyup="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type);">
```

How to change onKeyup with on blur using jquery so user will get validation message on leaving the email field?

Comment: Change `onkeyup` to `onblur`

Comment: How to change it on page load?
in $(document ).ready(function() { 

});

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery `blur()` and set `onkeyup` to `null` like in the snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById('Email').onkeyup = null;
  $('#Email').blur(function() {
    checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type);
  });
});

function checkconditions(v, n ,t) {
  alert('Blur');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="text  empty" type="text" size="20" name="Email" id="Email" value="" onkeyup="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type);">
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<input class="text  empty" type="text" size="20" name="Email" id="Email" value="" onkeyup="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type);">
```

with

```
<input class="text  empty" type="text" size="20" name="Email" id="Email" value="" onBlur="checkconditions(this.value, this.name, this.type);">
```